# Microsoft Azure Mobile App Service Backend Response Code 500

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I created a Mobile App (Android) on the Azure Portal with the C# backend language. After this I have downloaded the Visual Studio Project with the TodoItem-Example and added the Swagger Config.

In this picture you can see a request on the localhost. It works!
[image]

After this I published the example on azure and gets the following error:

[image]

Comment: Have you linked a database?  Do you have the relevant permissions to the database?  Is the TodoItem table created properly?  Are there any hints in the diagnostic logs (turn them on in your settings).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different things that can go wrong when publishing to Azure. The most likely issue is that your database is not set up correctly. The best way to find out what's happening is to turn on streaming logs and to look at the log output.

In the Azure portal, go to **Settings** -> **Diagnostic Logs** and turn on **Applicationg Logging (Filesystem)**. Note that this setting turns itself off after 12 hours to minimize the effect on site performance.

To view the logs, go to **Tools -> Log Stream**. To learn more about logging options, see [Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/).

For more debugging tips, see [Help, my app isn't working!](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!) in the Azure Mobile Apps Wiki.